# For how long can an Embraer E195 airplane glide at malfunction?

Tags: engine-failure, glide-ratio, embraer-e-jet

[E195 specs](https://www.embraercommercialaviation.com/commercial-jets/e195/):

- Maximum Takeoff Weight 52,290 kg
- Max Cruise Speed M 0.82
- Cruise altitude: 35000 feet

Assume the weather condition is perfect (no clouds or gust winds). Also assume this airplane is fully loaded and just reached cruising altitude at its max speed. There and then, both jet motors immediately stops due to malfunction. No fire or anything, they just stop.

Given this scenario; will this aircraft be able to "glide" downwards for an emergency landing, or will it just drop dead and head for the earth? If it won't glide, how long will it take until it reaches the ground for impact?

(Reason for asking: me, being horribly scared of flying, just took a trip with this exact plane model, and I could not get the above thoughts out of my mind)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2999/how-far-can-airplanes-glide

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How far can airplanes glide?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2999/how-far-can-airplanes-glide)

Comment: "will this aircraft be able to "glide" downwards for an emergency landing" All aircraft can. That's how wings work.

Comment: long in term of time or distance ?

Comment: I disagree this is a dupe as the question is more specific (it asks for one specific model)

Comment: When you ask "how long", are you asking for a duration or for a distance? (Both are linked through best glide speed)

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather 'clean' plane. Its maximum L/D is, probably, at least 14. (The table shows *cruise* L/Ds. The L/Dmax is probably much higher in all cases...) Properly handled, and from 35000ft, it might glide for more than 140 kms...

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift-to-drag_ratio :

[image]

Comment: 10 is horrible L/D. Modern airliners start around 18, probably more for the newest generation like E195.

Comment: @JanHudec the general aerodynamic configuration hasn't really changed much except for the much fatter GTFs, so I wonder if the power off L/D isn't actually slightly less than the previous ones.

Comment: @Jan Hudec  Yes, you're right. 10 was too little. Corrected...

Comment: You may provide the L/D ratio for the requested aircraft to answer the question

Answer (score -1):

Of course it will glide, and for many miles. The single engine plane that I flew would glide 9 times its altitude, and big commercial planes will glide even further.

As one relevant example, the Gimli Glider:  From Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimli_Glider

-Skip

Comment: I doubt you provide an answer. The question apply to E195 and is not as generic as [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2999/how-far-can-airplanes-glide).

Comment: @ManuH I answered the question, which was: "Given this scenario; will this aircraft be able to "glide" downwards for an emergency landing, or will it just drop dead and head for the earth?"  It will glide.  I cited the Gimli Glider as proof that certificated transport category aircraft glide rather well.  What don't you understand about this?

Comment: The question is: "For how long can an Embraer E195 airplane glide at malfunction?". It is aircraft specific (otherwise it would have been closed as dupe). The answer must be aircraft specific

Comment: @ManuH: L/D values aren't typically published. I personally see no value in the specific nature of the question. However, please have your say here: [Should the 'E195 gliding' question be closed or left open?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3816/14897)