# How and how often are the oxygen masks in the cabin checked?

Tags: airliner, aircraft-maintenance, cabin, oxygen-mask

Looking at [this old answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/12637/11787) I can see that oxygen masks check is mandatory for the flight deck. What about passenger masks?

- Is this check done daily on airliners?
- How is this check conducted and what is actually being checked?

Comment: Are you asking about the oxygen masks in the flight deck, or the cabin?

Comment: Both, if applicable, but I am generally more interested in the cabin masks, as these are in the hundreds(sometimes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a maintenance schedule to test the mechanism that causes the passenger masks to deploy(drop down). It is usually performed each 12 months. During this test, the masks themselves are inspected, any discrepancies found dealt with, and re-stowed in the little overhead box until the next scheduled inspection.

Answer (score 0):

Airlines conduct scheduled maintenance at 4 escalating levels. I don't recall the exact time or hours between visits but it looks something like this. "A"-Check is most frequent and takes a team of 1-3 mechs 1 shift to complete. "B"-Check takes 1 crew 1 shift to complete. "C"-check takes 1 crew 1 week to complete. HMV Heavy Maintenance Visit HMV takes 1 crew up to 2+ weeks to complete. As I recall pax O2 masks were checked/serviced during "C" checks (Rough Estimate: Yearly).