# Twin otter engine starting procedure

Tags: turboprop

Could you please give me the steps or procedure to start the a/c twin otter gas turbine engine?

Comment: Are you the owner? It should be in POH then. Otherwise can you provide more context why you want to know this procedure?

Comment: I am not an owner, but just want some info only.

Comment: For generic info http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/how-are-turbine-engines-started

Comment: At the beginning of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHTED7EmHlE) you can see the start up (done pretty quickly). Just turns on electric (above left window), checks battery, turns on fuel pumps (bottom middle panel) and then switches on the (electric) starter (above left window), waits a little for the engine to start turning and opens the condition lever (overhead panel) and waits a bit more for the engine to reach idle rpm.